# What is epsilon-delta defination of limit?What is it's geometrical meaning?

Tags: real-analysis

I know epsilon-delta defination but I can't compare it with the concept of right hand limit and left hand limit.Also a question arises in my mind which is "If a function is bounded and has a limit l at the point c then for sufficiently large epsilon l+epsilon does not correspond any functional value which fails to give delta neighbourhood of c if we think the concept geometrically."Am I right?If I am not please rectify my misconception with proper reason.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your title seems to have very little to do with the body of the question.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're trying to say here, but speaking of "sufficiently _large_ $\varepsilon$" sounds like it has a very small chance of being meaningful.

Comment: If you can locate a copy of Spivak's *Calculus*, then I recommend reading his long and helpful discussion of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

Comment: The question arises I prove the function f(x)=1/x,x€[1.infinity] the final inequality says that delta=9epsilon/(1-3epsilon).So,if we take epsilon>or=1 then delta becomes negative.How can it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bounded function which has a limit 1 as $x\rightarrow c$ if we take sufficiently large $\epsilon$, then $\epsilon +1 $ "does not correspond any functional value which fails to give delta neighborhood of c". You mean $\epsilon +1$ is large such that all correspond interval containing $c$ have functional values in the interval $( 1- \epsilon , 1 + \epsilon)$?. That's true.

In fact epsilon-delta proof said that if you take any interval containing the limit point in our case it is $1$ then you can find an interval containing $c$ such that the image of the interval contained in the interval contained $1$.

For example $f(x)= 2x - 3 $ has the limit $-1$ when $x$ approaches $1$. If you take the interval $(-1.25 , -0.75 )$ This contains the limit point $-1$. Now we search for an interval containing $1$ with the image contained in $(-1.1, -0.9) $ you can take $(0.9, 1.1)$. The image is $(-1.2,-0.8)\subset (-1.25, -0.75)$